# Android Swipe not working in Listview

Tags: android

I'm using multiple TABS and my tab swipe is working outside listview, but it is not working on ListView.

Below is code:

```
public class DistF7tabActivity extends AppCompatActivity  
implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView gv,gv2;    
    String arg;    
    CallServiceDist c1;    
    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dist_f7tab);
        tabHost=(TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
        spec1.setIndicator("Form");
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab01);
        tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Reasons");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab02);
        tabHost.addTab(spec2);    

        gv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        gv2 =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvT2);
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        gv2.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            Intent AcIntent = new Intent(DistF7tabActivity.this, DistF7ACtabActivity.class);
           startActivity(AcIntent);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("CATCH", e.toString());
        }

    }    

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {
        float lastX=0;
        switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
            // when user first touches the screen to swap
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                lastX = touchevent.getX();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                float currentX = touchevent.getX();

                // if left to right swipe on screen
                if (lastX < currentX) {

                    switchTabs(false);
                }

                // if right to left swipe on screen
                if (lastX > currentX) {
                    switchTabs(true);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void switchTabs(boolean direction) {
        if (direction) // true = move left
        {
            if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0)
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount() - 1);
            else
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabHost.getCurrentTab() - 1);
        } else
        // move right
        {
            if (tabHost.getCurrentTab() != (tabHost.getTabWidget()
                    .getTabCount() - 1))
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabHost.getCurrentTab() + 1);
            else
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: return `true` in `onTouchEvent` for success case.

Comment: @JunaidHafeez Thanks for detail, i tried, but it does not work.